# I'm in the US and computer only works when power supply is in 230V position. How do I diagnose this?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power, desktop-computer, diagnostic

So, I replaced a computer PSU about six months ago.  And, the computer power down intermittently.

I've found:

- it's not over heating.  Monitor shows it running cool.
- it's not graphics related.  Passes stress test.
- I can reproduce by grabbing app chrome, and moving window quickly (using Win8).
- it often powers down abruptly before it finishes booting.

Figure the new power supply is the issue.

Don't want to waste time, so looking to buy new computer.

Last ditch effort: change power supply setting from 115V to 230V.

**Setting the power supply to 230V works!**  Computer now works without a hitch!  But, why?  And, will it cause more damage?

Questions:

1. Is the power supply broke?
2. Is the red-switch-cover placed incorrectly?
3. Can I use the computer without damage?
4. How do I verify?

[image: Not my power supply switch]

Comment: A PSU with a voltage selector switch is not likely to be up to the quality of a more modern one which does not need a selector switch. You did not say what processor or motherboard is in the computer, so I can't say which [ATX power supply revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#ATX_power_supply_revisions) you need. I would be suspicious of your current power supply and not leave it plugged in unattended - make sure there is nothing flammable near it and be sure to have backups of all your data.

Comment: You could pursue the "why" it appears to be working, but it is not working as designed.  Whatever is allowing it to operate is not working as intended, so the possible consequences are unknown.  A replacement PSU is relatively inexpensive and eliminates whatever risk there might be, or the chance of failure at an inopportune time.

Comment: *"How do I verify?" -- Use a voltmeter (e.g. DMM) to check the +5 and +12 voltages on one of the Molex HDD power plugs.

Comment: It is not common, but still possible to have a 230v in the US.  I would get a volt meter first, and check the outlet, just to be sure!  If the volt meter says 230, then there is no problem. If the volt meter says 115 get a sledgehammer and beat this power supply to a pulp.  Then get a new one.

Comment: @cybernard *"It is not common, but still possible to have a 230v in the US"* -- Actually 220-240VAC is not just common, but very likely wired to the typical home.  It has two phases, which can be split into two 120V branch circuits.  The 240V is available for for high-power appliances such as electric oven, clothes dryer and stationay power tools.  But the 240V outlet is completely different from the 120V wall receptacle.  There is no way to confuse the two outlets, and a miswire would be a gross code violation..

Comment: @sawdust  Your house may have 1 or 2 appliance 240v outlets but it has 20+ regular outlets so that is <5% and not common.  "gross code violations"  this is the real world here, it could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's likely the 115V is broke, and the 230V circuitry is working fine, thus why it works.
2. It looks correct from the photo you supplied
3. In the short term, probably. You're technically "starving" your PC of power since the PSU has 230V available but is only drawing ~115V.

A power supply supplies power, it's not a transformer - so it's not going to all of a sudden boost your power supplied to 230V if you're not receiving that from the wall.
The 115V/230V on the back is only there for the purpose of setting the correct Input voltage, and different circuitry is used depending on which setting is selected. Maybe the 115V circuitry is broken and the 230V works fine (for now). If it's still got the voltage selector on the back, it's likely a shoddy PSU and should be replaced as soon as viable.

Comment: *"different circuitry is used depending on which setting is selected."* -- Not likely.  I inspected a similar PSU, and the "230V" setting simply engaged a voltage divider to cut the input voltage in half.  If the two settings didn't share most of the circuitry, it's not economical to put them in one box. *"it's likely a shoddy PSU"* -- The switch is not an indicator of quality.

Comment: "The switch is not an indicator of quality" - It definitely is today. Any manufacturers worth their salt spend the extra 50cents detecting voltage and setting it based on input. A practice that has been used almost everywhere for almost a decade.

Comment: @sawdust I didn't mean to imply most of the circuitry wasn't working or that they doubled up on the innards or something silly, only that clearly whatever is broken on the 115V line isn't on the 230V line.